# How to get list of folders from a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

how can i get a list of folders from a website?
Namely I wrote a program that take a URL
And give a list of folders from the website.
I try 
    Directory.GetDirectories(myURL)
but it not work.

Comment: It would be good if you can add some more information.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you will have to have the server run some code to get the list of directories. The client does not have access to the filesystem of the web server, and even using FTP or WebDAV the scope of what can be seen by the client will be limited.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a `folders.txt` file in every directory on your web server with the name of all child directories. Then use your favorite HTTP API to download the file and parse its contents.

As for websites that are beyond your control: you can't. However you can check if you have access to a folder with a specific name. That should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly access the file system on the web server (a .NET security feature).  You can however do this when you're running locally (under localhost), but I understand that's not the point.  If you're talking about submitting an URL that you don't own, then typically, no, that's not possible.